# Выбор языка formIt modx

Tags: modx, локализация, formit

Имеется сайт с несколькими контекстами и языками соответственно (ru, en, de, ...), а также используется `formIt` с таким шаблоном формы:

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="video" class="ajax_form white-popup-block">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="[[!+fi.name]]" />
    <span class="error error_name">[[!+fi.error.name]]</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="[[!+fi.email]]" />
    <span class="error error_email">[[!+fi.error.email]]</span>
    <input type="submit" value="[[%form.send?Topic=`label`]]" 
           class="f-bu f-bu-default" name="video-yes" id="yes_btn" />
</form>
```

Как сделать чтобы во всех контекстах, кроме 'ru', язык формы был английский?

Answer (score 1):

Пример из официальной документации ( http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/internationalization )

```
[[%key? &topic=`topicname` &namespace=`namespace_name` &language=`en`]]
```

Соответственно никто не мешает сделать

```
[[*context_key:is=`ru`:then=`
    [[%form.send?&topic=`label`&language=`ru`]]
`:else=`
    [[%form.send?&topic=`label`&language=`en`]]
`]]
```

Еще есть такой вариант:

```
[[$my_chunk_[[*context_key]]]]
```

и на выходе имеем чанки с названиями my_chunk_ru, my_chunk_en, my_chunk_de, ... в зависимости от контекста, но в данном конкретном случае первый вариант подходит больше.